# eth.getBalance is always 0 on fully synced geth ropsten

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

All accounts on my geth return 0 balance. The blockchain is fully synced. Latest messages show that it syncing seconds not days. When calling eth.syncing it returns false for over 2 days now. So it's done syncing 100%.
[image]

[image]

geth --datadir block --syncmode "fast" --ropsten --rpcapi eth,personal,web3,debug,txpool,net,admin,debug --rpc --gcmode full --rpcport=8547 --cache=4096

command I use to run geth.

and this is the balance that im trying to check: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x63b095C8fFE3feb0Db3b8Af5704145367Bc65f43

Any ideas? I'm going crazy over this. Do i need to try out other versions of geth?

Comment: what is the hash of the latest block? does it match the etherscan?

Comment: eth.blockNumber = 10641070 vs  etherscan = 10673064. so it does look like it's behind, but it's not syncing further. web3.eth.syncing = false

Comment: tx hash amount difficulty etc also differs from etherscan on same block number. so it looks like the network is totally different. Isn't --ropsten enough to be on the same network?

Comment: No, I didn't say "block number" , I said the *HASH* of the block. Block number doesn't mean anything, it is just a serie. Hash is all that matters

Comment: The hash of transaction and the hash of the block are different things

Comment: if you got the wrong Network chain check the hash of the block 0 , `eth.getBlock(0)` , this is the genesis and the hash of the genesis block must match on Etherscan

Comment: I'm resyncing the whole chain again. eth.getBlock(0) hash matches the network.